# Comparison between objects in Java

Tags: java

Is it possible to compare two concrete objects in Java and get a boolean as a result using the order operands ( =, <, >, >=, <= ) ?

boolean result = objectA < objectB ?

*`Being objectA and objectB concrete classes, not instances from Object.`*

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way to overload the built-in operators (including `<` `>` `<=` etc). Some languages have this feature, but Java doesn't.

You have to use a method. E.g. you could create an `isLessThan` method, and call it to see if one object is less than another.

The standard thing to do is to implement the built-in interface `Comparable`. Things like `TreeSet` (a built-in class that needs to compare objects) don't know about your `isLessThan` method, but they do know about `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to implement `Comparable` (or create a `Comparator`) and use the `compareTo(Object o)` method.

Since Java doesn't have operator overloading, you can't use operators with objects besides `=` to test for reference equality, and `+` for the String concatenation shorthand.

Comment: Technically you don't *have* to use Comparable or Comparator.